# Tedious updating multiple project that share same git repository as submodule

Tags: git

I have few core git repositories.  These repositories serve as core library used by more than 10 super projects.

From time to time, I may commit and push new changes (master branch) in these core git repository.  If I pull from super project and checkout submodules' master branch, I may see the new updated changes. However, the submodule directory become modified and I should add/commit the super project in order to make the super project advance to latest committed snapshot.  I should push the super project for team sharing.

Consider I have many super projects that share same core submodules.  That would be tedious to make such updates on super project itself one by one.

Is there any workaround or good practice to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure there is an "automatic" process to propagate submodules changes to all the parent projects (which are completely unknown from said submodules).

The other alternative is [gitslave gits](http://gitslave.sourceforge.net/), but it will not record the exact SHA1 of the submodule anymore.

Comment: I use smartgit as windows git gui.  Unfortunately, smartgit doesn't support gitslave.

Comment: @Chau In that case, I recommend scripting the process of updating each parent repos.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a feature ;-)

Rationale: When upstream changes library, projects that use it are still unaffected. Only when project team decides it is ready to use new version, someone pulls new submodule, checks if everything works and only then commits code using new version of submodule.